# injecting a list into a json format

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-controller

I'm new with angularJs and i want to inject a list of string that i get it using a restful web service into a jSON list.
And how can the connections list could proceed object returned by getAllConnectedApp.

```
angular
  .module('theme.core.navigation_controller', ['theme.core.services'])
  .controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', '$filter', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$interval',
    function($scope, $location, $timeout, filter, $http, $cookieStore, $interval) {
      'use strict';
      $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: '',
        useExternalFilter: true
      };
      $scope.connections = [];
      $scope.menu = [{
        label: 'HOME',
        iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home',
        url: '#/'
      }, {
        label: 'ORACLE MONITORING',
        iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked',
        children: [{
          label: 'SESSIONS',
          url: '#/general'

        }, {
          label: 'ADVANCED MONITORING',
          url: '#/advanced-monitoring'
        }, {
          label: 'CONFIGURATION',
          url: '#/configuration'
        }]
      }, {
        label: 'CODE TRACER',
        iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check',
        children: [{
              label: 'ADD CONNECTION',
              url: '#/addConnectionApp'

            },
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.connections.length; i++) {
              {
                label: $scope.connections[i],
                url: '#/codetracer',

              }
            }
          ]
          //url: '#/codetracer'
      }];

      $scope.getAllConnectedApp = function() {
        console.log("GET ALL CONNECTED APPLICATIONS...");
        $http.get("http://localhost:8090/api/personne/allConnection")
          .success(function(connections) {
            console.log(connections);
            $scope.connections = connections;
          });
      };

    }
  ]);
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: all the app can't be displayed

Comment: What means "can't be displayed"? is there any error in the web browser's console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for navigationController.js:61

Comment: angular.js:4117 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module themesApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module theme due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module theme.core.navigation_controller due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'theme.core.navigation_controller' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/nomod?p0=theme.core.navigation_controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have got syntax error over there, you can't have a loop inside object literal definition.

also, you portably want to update the menu only after getting back the response from the sever.
because your code was illogical as by the time you execute the loop, `scope.connections` is still an empty array.

something like this:

```
angular
    .module('theme.core.navigation_controller', ['theme.core.services'])
    .controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', '$location', '$timeout', '$filter', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$interval',
        function ($scope, $location, $timeout, filter, $http, $cookieStore, $interval) {
            'use strict';
            $scope.filterOptions = {
                filterText: '',
                useExternalFilter: true
            };
            $scope.connections = [];
            var connectionsMenu = [{
                label: 'ADD CONNECTION',
                url: '#/addConnectionApp'

            }];

            $scope.menu = [{
                label: 'HOME',
                iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home',
                url: '#/'
            }, {
                    label: 'ORACLE MONITORING',
                    iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked',
                    children: [{
                        label: 'SESSIONS',
                        url: '#/general'

                    }, {
                            label: 'ADVANCED MONITORING',
                            url: '#/advanced-monitoring'
                        }, {
                            label: 'CONFIGURATION',
                            url: '#/configuration'
                        }]
                }, {
                    label: 'CODE TRACER',
                    iconClasses: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check',
                    children: [connectionsMenu]
                    //url: '#/codetracer'
                }];



            $scope.getAllConnectedApp = function () {
                console.log("GET ALL CONNECTED APPLICATIONS...");
                $http.get("http://localhost:8090/api/personne/allConnection")
                    .success(function (connections) {
                        console.log(connections);
                        $scope.connections = connections;
                        for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
                            connectionsMenu.push({
                                label: connections[i],
                                url: '#/codetracer',
                            });
                        }
                    });
            };

        }
    ]);
```

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer, then i want that list of connections display when loading the page, so getting the responce from server must be en loading

Comment: Currently the menu will be dispalyed at first with only the `ADD CONNECTION ` item, 
because getAllConnectedApp  is async, you could use a loader and show the menu only after receiving the response, or if you are using `ui-router`, use the state resolve, to load the state only after fetching the menu.
see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki `resolve` section.